# Preventing buttons from moving on browser re size

Tags: css, html, resize, fullscreen

I am quite new to CSS so apologies in advance.

I have a simple problem: My navigation buttons move whenever I re size the window. I have Googled this for at least a week now and can't seem to find a solution.
I have managed to make it so that they do not move horizontally on re size, but for some reason they continue to move vertically on window re size. 
I really do not understand why this is happening!
Can anyone help?!
Thanks in advance.

Here is the HTML

```
`<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/experiment.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id= "wrapper">
        <a href:"#" class= "button1"> Home </a>
        <a href:"#" class= "button2"> About </a>
        <a href:"#" class= "button3"> How it works </a>
        <a href:"#" class= "button4"> Pricing </a>
        <a href:"#" class= "button5"> Contact </a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:960px;
}

.button1 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 20px;
    border: #122A0A;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 9px;
    background-color: #122A0A;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Georgia,serif; 
    color: #789D6C;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.button2 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 170px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    border: #122A0A;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 9px;
    background-color: #122A0A;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Georgia,serif;
    color: #789D6C;
}

.button3 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 320px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    border: #122A0A;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 9px;
    background-color: #122A0A;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Georgia,serif;
    color: #789D6C;
}

.button4 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 510px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    border: #122A0A;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 9px;
    background-color: #122A0A;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Georgia,serif;
    color: #789D6C;
}

.button5 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 660px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    border: #122A0A;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 9px;
    background-color: #122A0A;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Georgia,serif; 
    color: #789D6C;
}
```

I am trying to make a site with no scroll bars. (Just in case that is relevant)

Comment: Serious syntax errors in your markup. href: is wrong. also the whitespace after class and id attributes.

Comment: [Validate your document first](http://validator.w3.org/).  Come back if there are still problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML markup is wrong. it has to be like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="button1">Home</a>
    <a href="#" class="button2">About</a>
    <a href="#" class="button3">How it works</a>
    <a href="#" class="button4">Pricing</a>
    <a href="#" class="button5">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Also, absolute positioning each navigation item is the worst and hardest way to creat a navigation menu. i suggest you to look at a few articles for creating a simple navigation menu. here are a few:

- [super-simple-horizontal-navigation-bar](http://www.cssnewbie.com/super-simple-horizontal-navigation-bar/)
- [how-to-create-a-simple-horizontal-navigation-menu-from-scratch](http://css-plus.com/2010/03/how-to-create-a-simple-horizontal-navigation-menu-from-scratch/)
- [simple-navigation-bar-with-css-and-xhtml](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/simple-navigation-bar-with-css-and-xhtml/)